# Null reference when trying to access row of an Interactive Grid in Oracle APEX 18

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I need to write the value of selected item in an interactive grid into session.

It is working, but on page startup I get this error:

```
0: Unable to get property '20' of undefined or null reference
```

I am using a "Selection Changed [Interactive Grid]' dynamic action, with a javascript action as below:

```
function setItemValue(node) {
  $s('P3_SELECTED_REG_UID', node);              
  apex.server.process('MY_PROCESS',{
    pageItems: '#P3_SELECTED_REG_UID'
  },{dataType: "text"});
} 


var i, selectedIds = "",  
model = this.data.model;  

selectedIds = model.getValue(this.data.selectedRecords[0], "REGISTRATION_UID");    
console.log(selectedIds);
setItemValue(selectedIds);
```

The javascript action is set to NOT FIRE on initialization.  So I don't understand why I am getting this error.  The error disappears when I disable the dynamic action.

It all works fine, but I could do without a javascript error on page load.

Comment: did you try to change the function name?

Comment: I had to check that the selectedRecords array has non zero length, this solved it.